# How to refresh Android UI automatically

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on a project similar to a chat app, using TCP socket. I started a different thread separate from the UI thread where string messages are received from the socket, I am using a while loop to keep the socket open for a while, and I am using a The HANDLER method to update the UI after a message is received.

But on the receiving end, the UI does not update until the user touches the screen.
Please is there a way that the UI updates without the user touching the screen, or probably a way to refresh the UI automatically so that data received would be displayed to the user after being added to the list view that was created like a normal chat app.

Here is the code for my project.
This creates the server socket and keeps it open to receive the message from the client.

```
public void startListening(){
    myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6000);
                while(st) {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    Message clientMessage = Message.obtain();
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String strMessage = (String) ois.readObject();
                    clientMessage.obj = strMessage;
                    myHandler.sendMessage(clientMessage);
                    ois.close();
                }
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.obj = e.getMessage();
                myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    myThread.start();
}
```

Here is how I update the received data to the UI, which does not work until the screen of is touched.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message status){
        String myMessage = status.obj.toString();
        list.add(myMessage);
    }
};
```

If there is a way to refresh the UI automatically after `myMessage` is added to the `listView` so that the user just sees the message?

Comment: In handler after added myMessage just      use list adapter adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Thanks @RameshSambu, Let me  try that out.

Comment: Or add directly to an ArrayAdapter, not the Arraylist

Comment: @RameshSambu is right. Use Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Thanks you all. Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() works perfectly.